# Can I use enum in @Cacheable

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, enums, caffeine-cache

I would like to use enum in a @Cacheable as its cache name such as `@Cacheable(CacheName.CACHE_A.getName())`

I have a sample enum like

```
public enum CacheName {
  CACHE_A("CACHE_A");
  private final String name;
  CacheName(String name){
    this.name=name;
  }
  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
}
```

I tried to use it like a constant String as cache name in my service method

```
@Cacheable(CacheName.CACHE_A.getName())
public MyObject getObject(){ 
//return something 
}
```

This is not working.

It works when I declare a constant class with
`public static String CACHE_A = "CACHE_A";`

Is there any workaround if I prefer to use enum over a constant class, I do not see any difference as enum suppose to be fixed, right? please correct me, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using lombok then there is a neat trick to achieve that:

```java
@FieldNameConstants(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public enum CacheName {
    @FieldNameConstants.Include CACHE_A,
}
```

and then in your annotation you have access to a static field throught `Fields` subclass:

```java
@Cacheable(CacheName.Fields.CACHE_A)
public MyObject getObject(){
    //return something 
}
```

Tested on lombok version `1.18.28`.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public enum CacheName {
    CACHE_A(Names.CACHE_A);

    public class Names{
        public static final String CACHE_A = "CACHE_A";
    }

    private final String label;

    private CacheName(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.label;
    }
}
```

And in annotation you can use it like

```java
@Cacheable(CacheName.Names.CACHE_A)
public MyObject getObject(){ .. }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this is a good start but as I trying to use only enum, I will try with @Reveson solution

Comment: @sjvoon97 `FieldNameConstants(onlyExplicitlyIncluded` package is under lombok.experimental. this may consist bug and isnt finalized yet.

Comment: Thanks @Zahid I will check it out, might be getting back to using constant if there is no choice here

Comment: Yes, it is under lombok.experimental package, but please read on official site why:
`Experimental because: New feature; unsure if this busts enough boilerplate.`
It should be pretty safe to use. It is with us since version `1.16.22`. Ofcourse it was redesigned in `1.18.4` and `onlyExplicitlyIncluded` was added `1.18.8`. So the main feature is available for over 5 years. The `onlyExplicitlyIncluded` is available for over 4 years. 
Sources: 
- https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/FieldNameConstants
- https://projectlombok.org/changelog